# Bower ENOENT error on postinstall 'cd ... && npm i'

Tags: node.js, bower, cd

I have

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "cd ./bower_components/packagefromgit && npm i"
    }
}
```

in .bowerrc

The problem is that Bower throws

```
...
bower                                           postinstall cd ./bower_components/packagefromgit && npm i
bower                                                ENOENT spawn cd ENOENT

Stack trace:
Error: spawn cd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

And it is the same even with `"postinstall": "cd ."`.

Is there something wrong with using `cd` like that on Windows? How can this script be made cross-platform?

> System info:
>
> Bower version: 1.5.3
>
> Node version: 0.12.4
>
> OS: Windows_NT 6.1.7601 ia32

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that 'scripts' is a valid configuration for .bowerrc.  See https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md.

Perhaps you meant to put this in an NPM package.json?

Comment: This makes sense, though doesn't explain why I'm having problems with 'cd' in .bowerrc (from what I've seem it is not uncommon to use it there).